# Enumerate all registered Excel functions in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Using C# and Excel interop, how can I list all of the functions currently registered in Excel, along with their signatures (parameter names and types)?

In particular, I am interested in functions registered by C++ XLLs; I can get the information for the built-in functions by using reflection on the WorksheetFunction class.

Thanks,
Todd